# unable to install pdflatex using spyder

Tags: python, spyder, pdflatex

> ```
> pip install attrs==19.2.0 --user Collecting attrs==19.2.0   Using cached attrs-19.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (40 kB) Installing collected
> ```
>
> packages: attrs   Attempting uninstall: attrs
> Found existing installation: attrs 19.1.0
> Uninstalling attrs-19.1.0:
> Successfully uninstalled attrs-19.1.0 Successfully installed attrs-19.2.0 Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated
> packages. ERROR: pdflatex 0.1.3 has requirement attrs<19.0,>=18.2, but
> you'll have attrs 19.2.0 which is incompatible.
>
> pip install pdflatex --user Requirement already satisfied: pdflatex in
> c:\users\haris\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (0.1.3)
> Collecting attrs<19.0,>=18.2   Using cached
> attrs-18.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (34 kB) Installing collected
> packages: attrs   Attempting uninstall: attrs
> Found existing installation: attrs 19.2.0
> Uninstalling attrs-19.2.0:
> Successfully uninstalled attrs-19.2.0 Successfully installed attrs-18.2.0 Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated
> packages. ERROR: hypothesis 5.5.4 has requirement attrs>=19.2.0, but
> you'll have attrs 18.2.0 which is incompatible.
>
> need help to install pdflatex